# What is the best way to prevent visitors from excessively requesting resource-consuming pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am a newbie and trying to develop a Yellow-Pages like portal using ASP.NET MVC. 
I am wondering there will be some bad visitors who excessively request the portal pages to slow down my portal and to block request from other legitimate visitors.

My current idea is put a nugget (an embedded code block) in master page to check the interval between two consecutive request. If the interval is less than 5 seconds (for example), I will reject/terminate  to render the  request.

My question:

1. What is the best way to handle this issue?
2. If my idea above is applicable to solve this issue, what function must I call to terminate the rendering process (before doing resource-intensive job)?

---

**EDIT 1:**

1. Can we set this on server (IIS settings) globally instead of per application basis?

Answer (score 3):

If you are serving up read-only pages, then proper caching is your first line of defense. You can limit requests by IP, but that would necessitate another form of look-up.

Using any form of client control like adding a date entry to the master page is pointless if an attacker can side-step or remove it.

If you need to limit posts to a submission form, then you should start looking at authenticating users first and issuing tokens that allow one submission and refuse to issue a new token unless a certain time span has elapsed since the last token was issued.

Focus on making your site fast first.

Answer (score 1):

Re 1: make sure your pages render fast, use output cache. Get enough server power to handle visitors.

Re : Yes. it would also make sure people that are fast get blocked. Gratulations. Makes sense, but you ened t obe faster (0.1 seconds or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

I would do this via doughnut hole cache